# Independence and mutually exclusive; does either imply the other?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to get a good grasp on the relation between these two terms. so far with no luck.
Let $(\mathbb{P},\mathcal{F},\Omega)$ be a probability space (I hope I got the notations right).
Let $A,B\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be two non-empty events.
Let's say $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, meaning $A\cap B=\phi$.
Now, on one hand, we got: $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(\phi )=0$.
On the other hand; $\mathbb{P}(A)\neq 0$, and $\mathbb{P}(B)\neq 0$,
considering the last two lines, we have that: $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\neq \mathbb{P}(A) \mathbb{P}(B)$.

So, can I conclude that if two events are mutually exclusive that implies that they are dependent?
If the answer is yes, that doesn't make sense to me, since that will also imply that: $A,B$ are independent $\Rightarrow$ $A\cap B\neq \phi$.

Comment: Yes, of course. If two events (with nonzero probabilities) are independent, they are not mutually exclusive. If I toss two fair coins independently, and if $A$ is the event "first toss is heads" and $B$ is the event "second toss is heads", then $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac14$. Why doesn't that make sense to you? What makes you think it should be otherwise? Do you think that, if the two coin tosses are independent, that means that if the first one comes up heads, the second one has to come up tails??

Comment: Suppose $A=$ "heads on first toss", $B=$ "heads on second toss", $B'=\text{not-}B=$ "tails on second toss, and let's suppose that $A$ and $B$ are independent. What about $A$ and $B'$, do you agree that they are independent? Do you feel that $A$ and $B$ should be mutually exclusive, and likewise, $A$ and $B'$ should be mutually exclusive? So, if the first toss comes up heads, the second toss can't come up heads **or** tails? Does it vanish in thin air, or what?

Comment: I guess I don't quite get the idea of independence right. In your example, $\Omega =\left\{ HH,HT,TH,TT\right\}$, $A=\left\{ HH,HT\right\}$ and $B=\left\{ HH,TH\right\}$. Is there a different between saying "the second toss is independent on the first toss", and saying $A$ is independent of $B$?

Comment: To me, "the second toss is independent of the first toss" is just an informal way of saying that $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

Answer (score 2):

That is (almost) true.

For two events being independent, the probability of either of them must not change given the other has occurred. If the events are mutually exclusive, the probability of one of them given that the other occurred is $0$ - and thus two events can be both mutually exclusive and independent only if both have zero probability.

Comment: Almost. Two events are both mutually exclusive and independent if **at least one of them** has zero probability.

Comment: Almost. Two events are both mutually exclusive up to a null set and independent if at least one of them has zero probability. ;-)

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I use "mutually exclusive" to mean "P(A\cap B)=0", and I use "disjoint" to mean $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: @bof Sure, but that is not the terminology used by OP. Please note the smiley.